Is it possible to delete data in elastic from grafana with a specific index?
I have a data source with several indexes, but one of my indexes has an elastic column (called "NbCnx") and normally I only have integers, but I don't know why I have also had strings for 2-3 days. But now it's impossible to sum up all this data.
So, from grafana, can I delete the data from this index, or just convert the data or exclude the strings ?
Thank you for your help.
I have already done a test to convert the data into a grafana table but I can only have 10,000 rows on this table so I can only read 2 days of logs.

Grafana is for read only monitoring, unless you really-really put effort to do otherwise. If you want to delete something from your data source - do it outside of Grafana.

And if you want an advise on how to modify your query to elastic (from those who can help with that), it's probably a wise idea to share current query.

So the easiest way is to do a curl -X "DELETE" directly on my elastic with the index I want to delete ? Is there any other solution ?
